# Facebook API Adobe Air review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, air

I've an application which uses Facebook API and requires permissions:publish_actions, manage_pages. According to new FB policy I should send my application for approve to FB.
But I can't select any platform because it's an Adobe Air desktop application!!!
[image]

I tried to select Website ( because app located on website originally ) and posted url to download app. But they declined my request!

How to pass Adobe Air Desktop application for approval?

Comment: Adobe Air app is a native app right? I'd select Windows App if that app works on Windows. air also runs on ios and android correct?

Comment: It asks for store details for windows/osx/ios/android  apps. I don't have this app on any store it distributed through own site. Got some answer from Facebook Support team they want me to submit this app as "Web Application" but they already declined my first submit. Will talk to them in support. But anyway if any good idea  - I'm listening... :)